# java pdfbox printerjob wrong scaling / page format

Tags: java, pdf, printing, format, pdfbox

I'm trying to print an existing pdf file with pdfbox. Currently I'm using pdfbox 2.0.0 RC3 through maven.

This is my current code:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(myPdfFile));
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

if (job.printDialog()) {
    job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
    job.print();
}

document.close();
```

For testing I printed a test pdf with Adobe Acrobat and the same pdf with the few lines of code.
Everything works fine except for the borders. All borders (header, footer, left & right side) are to small and the footer is way too small.

Is there a magic method that I couldn't find in the world wide web for setting the right scaling/format?

Comment: Please look at the source of printWithPaper() in the Printing.java example. Does it help?

Comment: where do I find the Printing.java?

Comment: In the source code download https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x or here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/printing/  Btw see also the answer by Dato.

Comment: Oh great, I tried it but now the footer and the left side are too big. Header and right side didn't change.

Comment: You need to find out your own paper size. (paper.getWidth() etc)

Comment: I'm already using paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());

Comment: You need to adjust these values until it fits, i.e. substract or add something to these values. For example, there's often a physical margin at the left side of the paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this for pdfbox 2.0.0-RC3 version

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));
PDFPrintable printable = new PDFPrintable(doc, Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable(printable);
job.print();
```

Here is another version

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

// define custom paper
Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setSize(306, 396); // 1/72 inch
paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight()); // no margins

// custom page format
PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

// override the page format
Book book = new Book();
// append all pages
book.append(new PDFPrintable(doc, Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT), pageFormat, doc.getNumberOfPages());
job.setPageable(book);

job.print();
```

Comment: Intellij can't resolve 'PDFPrinter'. Is it in PDFBox 2.0.0-RC3? Because I can't use PDFBox 1.8.10. It has a bug with some fonts.

Comment: I had font problems with 1.8 version too. I am using PDFBox 2.0.0-snapshot `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: strange, it can't finde the dependency of the snapshot version. But it's finding RC1. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox here is no snapshot version either

Comment: you need to add this repository to download jar file. `<repository>
  <id>ApacheSnapshot</id>
  <name>Apache Repository</name>
  <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>`. I will try to use 2.0.0-RC3 , see if i come with the solution.

Comment: I added the snapshot version but it's still not resolving the PDFPrinter class. Also here https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#pdf-printing it's saying, that is removed. But there is no example how I can add e.g. Scaling.SCALE_TO_FIT

Comment: PDFPageable has a few parameters, but the only one that sounds right is setPage. But I don't know the pageIndex or even what it could be. Actually I guess that it should work with new Paper() but for that I have to print each time to see if it's right. That not that great

Comment: It works almost. Is there a way to change the values of the Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT? The footer must be about 5mm smaler and the right side about 1mm. Header and left side are now correct.

Comment: I already know about the Paper solution. But now I have to print the whole page each time to see if it fits or I'm wrong? Is `Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT` not a protest against `paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());`? Anyway, I will try it tomorrow morning

Comment: I tried the new solution. I ignored the `paper.setSize(306, 396);` part, because I don't know the size for an A4 paper  but `paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());` overwrites the `Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT` settings.

Comment: Have someone figured out what is the meaning of `job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(doc));` line in the second example as is contains also line `job.setPageable(book);`? Just a leftover from older code?