# Java printing existing pdf with right scaling

Tags: java, pdf, printing, scaling

I'm trying to print an existing PDF.

I already tried this: [java pdfbox printerjob wrong scaling / page format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479613/java-pdfbox-printerjob-wrong-scaling-page-format)

PDFBox is not working for me, because I can't get the right scaling of my PDF.
`Scaling.SHRINK_TO_FIT` is almost working but it's missing about 5mm and I can't add them because `paper.setImageableArea` is resetting it.

Also I tried to use `new Paper();` with own margins and without `setSize`, because I can't get the size of an DIN A4 paper. The problem with the margins is, if I'm getting the correct top & left size and then try to set the height and width then it's destroying the top & left position.

Now I'm looking for a free and simple solution without PDFBox to print a pdf file without losing the quality and the scaling.

Comment: Have you tried to just send it to the printer: Desktop.getDesktop().print(...)?

Comment: No, but I tried it now: `Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(pdfName));` and I get this exception: `java.io.IOException: Failed to print C:\Users\test.test\PDF.pdf. Error message: Der angegebenen Datei ist keine Anwendung zugeordnet.`. It's in German and translated it's saying: The giving file is not assigned to an application

Comment: You need to at least install one Pdf reader application.

Comment: I have Acrobad Reader DC, but I'm using Firefox for viewing and printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda silly but here is already the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35483083/4888475

My printed page was equal to the printed page from the Acrobat software and not to Firefox.