# Bad quality printing PDF with Java

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I have a Java application that opens a PDF and then prints it and does it well, but the print quality of the text is very bad.

If I print the same document from windows the PDF comes out without quality problems.

This is the code I use to open the PDF and print it:

```
File file = new File(pdf_path);

PDDocument document = null;

document = PDDocument.load(file);

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

PrintRequestAttributeSet pset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
pset.add(PrintQuality.HIGH);

job.setCopies(copias);

job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));

job.print(pset);
```

Examples:

Normal quality printing from windows
[image: Normal quality printing from windows]

Bad quality printing from application, Text is cut in some letters
[image: Bad quality printing from application]

[Pdf example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/thww3sra094tjvc/52174.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: What are the "quality problems" you speak of?

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35483083/2089675

Comment: I using PDFBox 2.0.17

Comment: And can you share the PDF?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr hello, now I added the link to the pdf in the question

Comment: Thanks. I tried printing from PDFDebugger and it looks excellent to me.